# SQL Query seems not to affect the same number of rows, Adding a count statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have made a query that looks like this

***Query 1.***

```
  SELECT zlec_status.nazwa                       AS Status, 
           piorytet.nazwa                          AS Priorytet, 
           Concat(koord.imie, ' ', koord.nazwisko) AS `Koordynator`, 
           Concat(zlec_adresy.miasto, ' - ', zlec_adresy.ulica, ' ', 
           zlec_adresy.oddzial) 
                                                   AS `adres`, 
           zlec_z_dnia,zlec_id, 
           zlec_nr, 
           zlec_do, 
           zlec_ogran, 
           awizacje, 
           awizacja_na_dzien, 
           termin_zamkniecia, 
           tresc, 
           uwagi 
    FROM   zlec 
           INNER JOIN koord 
                   ON zlec.koord = koord.id 
           INNER JOIN zlec_adresy 
                   ON zlec.zlec_addres = zlec_adresy.id 
           INNER JOIN piorytet 
                   ON zlec.priorytet = piorytet.id 
           INNER JOIN zlec_status 
                   ON zlec.status_zlecenia = zlec_status.id
```

And the following one which is a ordinary one

***Query 2.***

```
SELECT * FROM zlec;
```

The thing is the first one returns ( affects by executing )  48 rows where the second query returns 103 rows. What could be the possible cause of this?

I will also show you my dumb of the sql in case you would like to make a run on your own http://pastebin.com/cMPAtxCU .

**Subquestion** - quite no point starting of with a new question for that because its also connected with the row count affect.

Besides I was wondering how can I get into the first query a count(*) to get the affected rows - it has to be done in sql I cannot use php code for that, probably it would be good to use a limit 1 for the count.

Comment: Well they are vastly different, the first requires all the join conditions be met - which they are not for all rows in `zlec` as the count differs.  Add joins one by one until the row count differs.

Comment: The `inner join`s filter out records.  If you don't want this behavior, use `left join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `INNER JOIN`, if one of your other tables, `koord`, `zlec_adresy`, `piorytet` and `zlec_status` is missing a record corresponding to a record in `zlec`, that record in `zlec` will not be in the result set.  If you want every record in `zlec` to appear, you have to use `LEFT JOIN`.  Check out:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

For a pretty good explanation.

Comment: Yes the left join does it work, didn't thought it could be that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

With your additional inner joins rows might be eliminated. Have you tried adding the inner joins to your "Select * FROM zlec;"?